# not able to send confirmation email while signing up using rest-auth

Tags: django-rest-auth

i am getting an error while using rest framework it says Exception Type: AttributeError at /rest-auth/registration/ Exception Value: module 'users' has no attribute 'get_full_name()'  Request information: USER: AnonymousUser

Template error:

> In template /Users/apple/Desktop/workffbase/workforfilms-master-DJG/templates/account/email/email_confirmation_message.txt, error at line 2
>          module 'users' has no attribute 'get_full_name()'
>          1 : {% load account %}
>          2 :  {% user_display user.email as user_display %} 
>          3 : {% load i18n %}
>          4 : {% autoescape off %}
>          5 : {% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!
>          6 : 
>          7 : You're receiving this e-mail because user {{ user_display }} has given yours as an e-mail address to connect their account.
>          8 : 
>          9 : To confirm this is correct, go to {{ activate_url }}
>          10 : 
>          11 : {% endblocktrans %}
>          12 : {% endautoescape %}

Answer (score 0):

just needed to modify ACCOUNT_USER_DISPLAY to correct value in setting files but still after verification no email received through smtp.